# command-line file download from website without wget or curl

Tags: html, ui-automation

I need to automate a file download from a website. The website operators have blocked `wget` and `curl`; they have also blocked use of `lynx`. I'm not sure **how** they are being blocked, but when I download a webpage from the site - or an individual file - all I get is a small text file that includes the following statement:

```
Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
```

Cookies **are** enabled, so not having JavaScript enabled is apparently the issue. AFAIK, it's not possible to "enable" Javascript in `curl`, `wget` or `lynx`.

These download (attempts) are being run from a headless server; I don't have access to a conventional web browser on that machine. Nevertheless, I need to **automate** this file download, and I wondered if it was possible to *script* a GUI browser from my desktop machine (Apple). I fiddled around with some AppleScript for Safari, but it's poorly documented & I've made no real forward progress.

If it makes any difference: I have the URL for the file I want to download. Despite the innuendo from one of the commentors, I am only trying to save myself a bit of time by automating the file download process; i.e. replacing the labor-intensive GUI browser download, pointing, clicking & saving with a script/automation technique.

Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the site may have done this to PREVENT the kind of scraping you're trying to do, to protect their copyrighted information.  Google and Firefox can both run in "headless" mode, and you can control it from languages like Python using Selenium.

Comment: @TimRoberts: AFAIK, there aren't any *copyright* issues ( I certainly wouldn't try to break the law!) - this is an open forum website. There's one page with a file that can be downloaded, and that file changes a few times per year typically. That's all that's going on - nothing nefarious.